# Direction, Orientation object

Tags: c, animation

How do I move an object according to its orientation? I mean, I have a cube in one position, I want to rotate about the Y axis and move according to their orientation. Then move and rotate again to change your direction. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can extract the axis directly from the transformation matrix. How are you transforming the object?

Comment: I use glRotatef -> glTranslatef

Answer (score 0):

in JS you can try something like this:

```
var previousPosition = [x, y]; //change x and y with the coordinate of the object
var nextPosition = [x, y]; //change x and y with the new coordinate of the object

var x = previousPosition[0] - previousPosition[0];
var y = nextPosition[1] - nextPosition[1];

var rad = Math.atan(y/x);
var deg = rad * 180 / 3.14;
```

in the variable deg you have the value in degree to rotate your cube